# Access the first characters of a document ID in Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'd like to get the document ID and compare the first X characters of that ID to a string such that specific UIDs can access all documents with that prefix.

Ignoring prefixes for now, I tried to compare the full document ID using [resource.id](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource) but received permission denied in the client-side app. Permission is granted comparing `request.auth.uid` only so it's not a client-side issue.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /collectionA/{x} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == 'ABCD1234' && resource.id == '00153@1529943514.26';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For your rule, `x` is the document id string, so you can compare against that instead of resource.id (perhaps it's not been determined that the user has access to any property of the resource yet).

You have a number of ways to check the contents of a [String](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String) (definitely read that link).

You can extract a substring using a indexing syntax:

```
x[0:2] == 'abc'  // the first three characters of the string x
```

You could also use [matches()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches) to apply a regular expression to check the beginning of a string:

```
x.matches('^prefix.*') == true
```

Comment: I've amended the rule to use `x` instead of `resource.id` and still receiving permission denied. Tested with brand new blank doc named 'test' and still denied. Tested auth only and permission was granted. The document ID is the name displayed in Firestore, correct?

Comment: Are you testing from a client app or using the rules emulator in the console?